# PHP preg_match with a different number

Tags: php

I have question about `preg_match`. My full sentence is:

> height: 100 cm wooden door.

And result is: `cm`. What i need to change that number before cm is not the same and can be diffrent in each sentences.

```
preg_match("/height: 100 (.*)wooden door/i",$str,$number);
```

Thank you

Comment: Can it be a number containing decimals? If not, you can try `\d+`

Comment: it works! thank you

Comment: You can use [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) to test your regular expressions or search examples.

Comment: To *change* the number eg: [`preg_replace('/\b\d+(?=\s+cm\b)/', "101", $str);`](https://www.phprun.org/TkqbDY) [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7bA6w1/1)